# How to find the count of items in a block?

Tags: nodes, blocks

I have a block named *views-view-fields--our-services--block.tpl.php* i need to find the no of nodes under this block.How do find the total no of nodes displaying inside a block?

Comment: Have you trying to use any module ? Or you can do this by using custom code ?

Comment: no i am not using any module. i need this custom coded inside this block view template.

Comment: I know you are not using any module. I just ask you that trying to use any module ?

Comment: do you need the information in the block, or in the page outside the block?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, for **HEADER** (located in the middle of the edit view screen) **Add a Global Result Summary**. Then just use the **@total** token like in the picture below. This will count the number of rows in your view.

[image]